# Inline comment in PlantUML

Tags: markdown, uml, plantuml

Is it possible to write an inline comment in the **PlantUML** (Markdown format)?

For example, I would like to achieve the following result

```
@startuml
    participant Alice as A
    participant Bob as B

    A -> B    ' Here I would like to have my comment
    ...
@enduml
```

I know that the following notations can be used:

```
' This is a comment on a single line
A -> B: Hello World
/' Multiple
comment
lines '/
```

What I find strange is that this style:

```
participant Alice as A    /' Why does this comment work? '/
```

**works for the participants** and can be used successfully. Only with the references this does **not** work.

The solutions with the `'` and `--` notation which were mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003075/can-i-write-comments-in-uml-class-diagram) do not work properly.

> I already checked the following sources:
>
> - https://forum.plantuml.net/1353/is-it-possible-to-comment-out-lines-of-diagram-syntax
> - https://plantuml.com/de/commons

Is there a possibility here?

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest spacification, you have three options to add comment section in a `*.puml` file:

**1) Simple comment**

Everything that starts with simple quote `'` is a comment.

```
@startuml
'Line comments use a single apostrophe
@enduml
```

**2) Block comment**

Block comment use C-style comments except that instead of `*` you use an apostrophe `'`, then you can also put comments on several lines using `/'` to start and `'/` to end.

```
@startuml
/'
many lines comments
here
'/
@enduml
```

**3) Put block comment on the same line**

```
@startuml
/' case 1 '/   A -> B : AB-First step 
               B -> C : BC-Second step
/' case 2 '/   D -> E : DE-Third step
@enduml
```

Reference: [QA-3906](https://forum.plantuml.net/3906/can-a-block-quote-begin-and-end-on-the-same-line) and [QA-3910](https://forum.plantuml.net/3910)